# Rack tool for measuring cabling?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a tool that can be used to measure the length of Cat 6 cables that need to be installed in a comms rack. I won't be making the cables myself.
For example the length of a cable required between a switch at the bottom of the rack and the patch panel at the top. I could use Visio but it may give me inaccurate results.
The lengths of these cables can then be given to a data cabler to install them in the rack.
I've come across a couple of tools, http://racktables.org/ and http://flux.org.uk/projects/rackmonkey/ but they don't suit my purpose.

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic, but you need to measure the length of cable needed to go from point A to point B in a rack? Isn't a tape measure the appropriate tool for the job? I mean, you have to physically measure the distance, right?

Comment: I expect the OP is looking for a recommendation for a suitable long, flexible tape measure with a means of managing the excess length.

Comment: A tape measure isn't always ideal, because of the inflexibility of them, and their inability to get through small holes, and the fact that you then have to measure 45 times for 45 different network sockets, and also make sure you have enough slack to slide the server out on its rails without unplugging it (if required). I can say that I can sympathise, however it's also pretty simple to estimate accurately once you've actually done a rack or two.

Comment: You could always use a long cable, plug one end in the server, run it all the way to wherever you want it and then unplug it and measure how long that was. If you're having a hard time with your tape measure for whatever reason.

Comment: Hi, Maybe I didn't make myself clear but the scenario I have in mind is for 100 racks all with different devices installed.

Comment: If a tape measure doesn't work, string. Seriously. Assuming you have 100 racks with *similar* equipment you should only need a few measurements to duplicate, and measure the resulting string lengths.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a 1/2" or 1/4" tape measure.  You should be able to find these at home depot or a fabric shop (the 1/4").  They should be small enough to fit through the holes in the rack.